# java.lang.IllegalStateException: CDI is not available

Tags: jsf, primefaces, glassfish

I am using Netbeans 16 to create a web project with Gradle with Jakarta EE 9 and PrimeFaces 12. The basic project creation works and deploys correctly on the Glassfish 6.2.5 server.

When adding the Jakarta EE and PrimeFaces dependencies (without making any other modifications to the project), when deploying it to the Glassfish server the following error is generated:

Error occurred during deployment: Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: CDI is not available. Please see server.log for more details.

Project files are as follows:

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'jacoco'
apply plugin: 'war'

group = 'mygroup'
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    
    testImplementation     'junit:junit:4.13'
    compileOnly 'jakarta.platform:jakarta.jakartaee-api:9.1.0'
    implementation 'org.primefaces:primefaces:12.0.0:jakarta'

}
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app version="5.0"
    xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee/web-app_5_0.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>jakarta.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
   
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>jakarta.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

**glassfish-web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
    Copyright (c) 1997, 2018 Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
    
    This program and the accompanying materials are made available under the
    terms of the Eclipse Public License v. 2.0, which is available at
    http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-2.0.

    This Source Code may also be made available under the following Secondary
    Licenses when the conditions for such availability set forth in the
    Eclipse Public License v. 2.0 are satisfied: GNU General Public License,
    version 2 with the GNU Classpath Exception, which is available at
    https://www.gnu.org/software/classpath/license.html.

    SPDX-License-Identifier: EPL-2.0 OR GPL-2.0 WITH Classpath-exception-2.0
-->
<!DOCTYPE glassfish-web-app PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Servlet 3.0//EN" "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-web-app_3_0-1.dtd">
<glassfish-web-app error-url="">
  <class-loader delegate="true"/>
  <jsp-config>
    <property name="keepgenerated" value="true">
      <description>Keep a copy of the generated servlet class' java code.</description>
    </property>
  </jsp-config>
</glassfish-web-app>
```

I have performed two tests:

- I remove the dependency on primefaces and the error is no longer generated.
- I make a copy of another project that is working (it deploys correctly), I delete all files except build.gradle, web.xml and glassfish-web.xml and it generates again the error "java.lang.IllegalStateException: CDI is not available".

Comment: Can you post the full stacktrace so we can see where this error originates from?

Comment: hi @Melloware, se my answer for the stacktrace and related issue on the GlassFish tracker.

Answer (score 2):

You need to enable the CDI functionality in your application. Either create an empty beans.xml file in the WEB-INF directory, or create some class and add @ApplicationScoped annotation on that class.

Why:

Primefaces starts the JSF container. In GlassFish 6, the JSF container needs CDI functionality. But there’s “design flaw” in GlassFish 6, because JSF will not start the CDI if it’s not already started. If there’s nothing in your app that triggers CDI, you get this error.

I reproduced this error, just by placing the PrimeFaces Jakarta JAR into a plain Jakarta EE 10 without any CDI elements, on GlassFish 7 (yes, the same behavior as in GlassFish 6).

If you're interested in stacktrace, here it is (on GlassFish 7.0.6):

```
  Critical error during deployment: 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: CDI is not available
    at com.sun.faces.util.Util.getCdiBeanManager(Util.java:1494)
    at com.sun.faces.el.ELUtils.addCDIELResolver(ELUtils.java:199)
    at com.sun.faces.el.ELUtils.buildFacesResolver(ELUtils.java:166)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationAssociate.initializeELResolverChains(ApplicationAssociate.java:416)
    at com.sun.faces.application.applicationimpl.ExpressionLanguage.performOneTimeELInitialization(ExpressionLanguage.java:144)
    at com.sun.faces.application.applicationimpl.ExpressionLanguage.getELResolver(ExpressionLanguage.java:89)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.getELResolver(ApplicationImpl.java:200)
    at com.sun.faces.el.ELContextImpl.<init>(ELContextImpl.java:60)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3911)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.contextListenerStart(WebModule.java:601)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4450)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:551)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:935)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:917)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:644)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1796)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1484)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:88)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:97)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:262)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:353)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:535)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:259)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:467)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:570)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:566)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at java.base/javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:376)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:565)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:596)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:588)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at java.base/javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:376)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:587)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1478)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1847)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1723)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:535)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:222)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandlerBase.service(StaticHttpHandlerBase.java:150)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:425)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:144)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:174)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:153)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:196)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:88)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:246)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:118)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:96)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:51)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:510)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:82)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:83)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:101)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:535)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:515)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

This issue was already reported in https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/glassfish/issues/24336. But I'm not sure this is a bug in GlassFish or expected behavior.

Comment: JFYI: PrimeFaces doesnt start anything. PrimeFaces ist just a component lib. If JSF isnt started/configured, PrimeFaces will just do nothing.

Comment: It's not true. PrimeFaces JAR contains faces-config.xml, which is detected by GlassFish, which then triggers initialization of the Faces engine. GlassFish Faces engine (Mojarra) requires that CDI container is already initialized and fails to start if it isn't. So, just by placing the PrimeFaces JAR into the app that doesn't trigger CDI container, you get the "CDI is not available" deployment error. To fix it, you need to modify the app to trigger initialization of the CDI container as I described in my answer.

Comment: then GlassFish starts JSF, not PF :)

Comment: Yes, technically you’re right :)